# Using CMD: List all Mp4 in folder AND list their durations

Tags: cmd.exe, csv, list

I am currently using the follow code to create a `file.CSV` file with a list of all .mp4 titles:

```
dir /s /b *.mp4 > listmp4.csv
```

I want to include the duration of each video in my list.
What should my command line be?

I want these numbers in the CSV too:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, CMD has no way, without using WScript scripting, to fetch metadata attributes such as *Duration*, *Composers*, or *Bit Rate*. However, [*PowerShell* does provide the facility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830853/powershell-get-video-duration-and-list-all-files-recursively-export-to-csv) to gather that information.

The following script, adapted [from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830853/powershell-get-video-duration-and-list-all-files-recursively-export-to-csv), run in *PowerShell*, scans the folder recursively and pipes *Folder*, *Filename* and *Duration* to a CSV.

```
$Directory = "E:\Audio Files\_.mp3\Albeniz, Isaac"
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Recurse -Force | ForEach 
{
    $Folder = $Shell.Namespace($_.DirectoryName)
    $File = $Folder.ParseName($_.Name)
    $Duration = $Folder.GetDetailsOf($File, 27)
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Folder = $_.DirectoryName
        Name = $_.Name
        Duration = $Duration}} | Export-Csv -Path "C:/temp/out.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

It creates the CSV displayed below.

[image: CSV displayed in LibreOffice Calc]

Modify the script as needed for location of files and to show or hide the metadata.

Comment: I get this error:
At line:8 char:21
+     [PSCustomObject]@
+                     ~
Unrecognized token in source text.
At line:8 char:21
+     [PSCustomObject]@
+                     ~
Unexpected token '@' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnrecognizedToken

Comment: Make sure you have the latest POowerShell; this runs on Windows 10 *as is*. Try the script again... it's been restyled. Also try that in StackOverflow cited. Both worked on my PC. Also: have you changed paths to suit your PC?

Answer (score 0):

Use **[ffprobe.exe (FFmpeg)](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)** in a loop inside your folder where you have the files you want to list

```c
@echo off 

cd /d "D:\Path\To\mp4\Videos\Folder\"
set "_ffprobe=C:\Program Files\FFmpeg\Bin\ffprobe.exe"
for /R %%I in (*.mp4)do @for /f eol^=^|delims^=. %%i  in ('
@"%_ffprobe%" -i "%%~fI" -show_entries format^=duration -v quiet ^
-of csv^="p=0" -sexagesimal^|findstr/e .[0-9]')do echo\"%%~nxI",'0%%~i>>".\file.csv"
```